# ContentProvider android permission

Tags: android, database, sqlite, permissions, android-contentprovider

I'm hoping someone smarter then me can answer this question.

By default can all android databases be accessed through the ContentProvider, or does the application in question have to explicitly give permissions to share it with the CP before another program can access its db?

If they are not shared by default, short of getting the application developer to include the change, root would be the only way around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By default can all android databases be accessed through the ContentProvider, or does the application in question have to explicitly give permissions to share it with the CP before another program can access its db?

By default, a `ContentProvider` is exported, meaning third parties can perform CRUD operations upon it. You can change this behavior either by:

- Marking it as not exported (`android:exported="false"` on the `<provider>` element)
- Using your own custom permissions to allow the user to conditionally allow access to the provider

> If they are not shared by default, short of getting the application developer to include the change, root would be the only way around it?

Root will not help you access another applications' content provider. Please respect the wishes of the other developer.